# Vending machine implementation

Tags: java, console

How would one optimize this code?

```
import java.util.*;
public class VendingMachineAssignement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double item1 = 1.25;
        double item2 = .75;
        double item3 = .90;
        double item4 = .75;
        double item5 = 1.50;
        double item6 = .75;

        System.out.print("Enter an item number: ");
        int item = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the amount paid: ");
        double paid = keyboard.nextDouble();

        if (item == 2 || item == 4 || item == 6)
        {
            if (paid >= item2)
            {
                System.out.println("Thank you for buying item " + item + ", your change is $" + (paid-item2) + ". Please come again!");
            }
            if (paid < item2)
            {
                System.out.println("Please insert another " + "$" + (item2-paid));
            }
        }

        else if (item == 1)
        {
            if (paid >= item1) 
            {
                System.out.println("Thank you for buying item " + item + ", your change is $" + (paid-item1) + ". Please come again!");
            }
            if (paid < item1)
            {
                System.out.println("Please insert another " + "$" + (item1-paid));
            }
        }
        else if (item == 3)
        {
            if (paid >= item3) 
            {
                System.out.println("Thank you for buying item " + item + ", your change is $" + (paid-item3) + ". Please come again!");
            }
            if (paid < item3)
            {
                System.out.println("Please insert another " + "$" + (item3-paid));
            }
        }
        else if (item == 5)
        {
            if (paid >= item5) 
            {
                System.out.println("Thank you for buying item " + item + ", your change is $" + (paid-item5) + ". Please come again!");
            }
            if (paid < item5)
            {
                System.out.println("Please insert another " + "$" + (item5-paid));
            }
        }


    }

}
```

And also, for example, if I enter `5` for `item` and `.10` for `paid`, then why does it say `Please insert another $1.4` instead of 1.40? Even though 1.50 - 1.4 and 1.50 - 1.40 would be the same, how come it does not display `1.40`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Things I would fix:

All of your condition test statements do exactly the same thing.

> ```
> else if (item == 1)
> {
>     if (paid >= item1) 
>     {
>         System.out.println("Thank you for buying item " + item + ", your change is $" + (paid-item1) + ". Please come again!");
>     }
>     if (paid < item1)
>     {
>         System.out.println("Please insert another " + "$" + (item1-paid));
>     }
> }
> else if (item == 3)
> {
>     if (paid >= item3) 
>     {
>         System.out.println("Thank you for buying item " + item + ", your change is $" + (paid-item3) + ". Please come again!");
>     }
>     if (paid < item3)
>     {
>         System.out.println("Please insert another " + "$" + (item3-paid));
>     }
> }
> ...
> ```

You can use arrays to help solve this issue.

```
double[] prices = new double[] { 1.25, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 1.5, 0.75 };
```

Then you can access those specific values with `prices[item - 1]`.  Remember that arrays start with the index `0`, so without subtracting 1 you will end up with an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).  The comparison is now simplified.

```
if (paid >= (prices[item - 1]))
{
    System.out.println("Thank you for buying item " + item + ", your change is " + (paid - prices[item - 1]) + ". Please come again!");
}
```

---

You ask the user to insert more money, but never actually allow him to.

> ```
> if (paid < item2)
> {
>     System.out.println("Please insert another " + "$" + (item2-paid));
> }
> ```

This can easily be solved with a `while` loop and another pair of input request statements.

---

You never close your `Scanner` when you are finished with it (a memory issue).

```
keyboard.close();
```

---

You never check if the item you buy is actually within the bounds of the array length.

```
if (!(item <= prices.length))
{
    System.out.println("Sorry, we don't have that item in stock.");
    keyboard.close();
    return;
}
```

---

When working with money, it is hard to work with `doubles`, they are too imprecise.  An example of this is that `0.42 - .21` is likely something like `0.209999999999999997` rather than `0.21` exactly.

We are going to use the [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class to make sure that the our `double` values will stay accurate.

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number)
```

---

### Recommendations that are optional:

Don't do this:

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> ```

It could be problematic for the compiler to import a bunch of packages at once. If two packages provide the same type, both are imported, and the type is used in the class, a compile-time error occurs. This is described in [JLS 6.5.5.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#32799):

> Otherwise, if a type of that name is declared by more than one type-import-on-demand declaration of the compilation unit, then the name is ambiguous as a type name; a compile-time error occurs.

In addition, it also saves a bit of memory.  And your IDE (if you use one), should have the ability to do this automatically.

---

You might note that this:

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

Is a bit different than your usual:

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> ```

They both do the same thing, but one uses [variable arity parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java/2926653#2926653).

---

The [`Scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method does not read the *last newline* character of your input, and thus a *newline* could be consumed if you call [`Scanner.nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29).  I prefer to use `Scanner.nextLine` since you can input any valid `String`, and then just parse it into the type you need (as long as it's a valid type to parse it to).

---

### Final code:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] prices = new double[] { 1.25, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 1.5, 0.75 };
        int item = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter an item number: ");
        item = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        if (!(item <= prices.length))
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, we don't have that item in stock.");
            keyboard.close();
            return;
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the amount paid: ");
        double paid = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());

        while (paid < (prices[item - 1]))
        {
            System.out.print("You need " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(Math.abs((paid - prices[item - 1]))) + " more for item " + item);
            paid += Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for buying item " + item + ", your change is " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((paid - prices[item - 1])) + ". Please come again!");

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `keyboard.close();` - why? It'll just get collected when the function ends, which is the very next thing that happens.

Comment: You say that it's hard to work with doubles, but you don't really fix the problem; you just change how they're displayed. If the user puts in 30 cents 3 times, this program will think the user still needs to input a tiny fraction of a nanocent to pay for item 3.

Comment: @user2357112 - `keyboard` *goes out of scope* when the method terminates, but the GC choose when to clean it up. In a tiny program like this, that will occur immediately when the program itself terminates, but you never know in a longer-running program. Better to pick up good habits early.

Comment: @DavidHarkness: Yeah, that was a mistake; I should have said it becomes collectable when the function ends. Even if you close it, the GC *still* decides when to collect the resources, so closing it won't help with memory. The only effect it has is closing `System.in`, and I don't know whether or not that counts as a positive.

Comment: @user2357112 - True, but if the scanner were backed by a file rather than `System.in`, the file's input stream is closed immediately.

Comment: `Then you can access those specific values with prices[item - 1]. Remember that arrays start with the index 0, so without subtracting 1 you will end up with an off-by-one error.` - Or you can put a dummy value at `price[0]`, so item matches index.  It's what I tend to do in anything more complex than this, so you don't have to mix'n'match for comparisons.

Comment: I don't see much of a problem with `import java.util.*`. The classes in that package are very well known; name clashes are highly unlikely (`java.sql.Date` aside), and I'd argue that `java.util` deserves priority naming rights anyway. Also, the `import` makes no difference to the program's runtime performance.

Comment: @syb0rg: You should probably add something to check against the hilariously easy to hit array overflow condition.

Comment: @syb0rg: Enter an item number of 15.

Answer (score 8):

To start of, if using amount of variables of the same data-type, the appropriate way of doing such a thing is an Array; specific case, double [] prices;

An array will allow you to keep a reference to all your values and allowing you to make a single if-else instead of each for every item.
Demo:

```
double [] prices = {1.25, 0.75, 0.90, 0.75, 1.50, 0.75};
System.out.print("Enter an item number: ");
int item = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the amount paid: ");
double paid = keyboard.nextDouble();
if (paid >= prices[item-1])
     System.out.println("Thank you for buying item " + item + ", your change is $" + (paid-prices[item-1]) + ". Please come again!");
else
     System.out.println("Please insert another " + "$" + (prices[item-1]-paid));
```

you could make a helper function to add another zero to a string if you want to, like you wanted in 1.4 to become 1.40, another way is to use String.format("%.2f",(paid-prices[item-1])); to get the string.

Hope that helps.
Please ask if anything isn't clear.

EDIT: changed to output to decremented value of item since an Array starts with 0, and user's requested first item to be 1.

Comment: initializing the array can be done like this: `double[] prices = new double[]{ 1.25, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 1.5, 0.75 };`

Comment: Changed due to suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, damn Firefox submitted the comment when I fixed spelling. See the edit of the comment :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a block of code with comments below.

Always consider exceptional cases. That is a crucial part of programming.

```
// Only import what you need.
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Use an array if you have a list.
        double[] itemPrices = {1.25, .75, .90, .75, 1.50, .75};

        // This array starts from 0 end ends at 5.
        // Corresponding to item #1 to #6.
        int maxItem = itemPrices.length;

        // Have we been given an item that is Ok yet?
        boolean itemFound = false;

        // We have not been provided an item # yet. This will have to be non-null
        // once we exit the do-while statement below.
        Integer item = null;

        // read an item number until an existing item is found.
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter an item number: ");
            try {
                item = keyboard.nextInt();
                if ( item >= 1 && item <= maxItem ) {
                    itemFound = true;
                } else {
                    // Inform the user of the problem. Give them another chance.
                    // String.format is very neat stuff. Use it.
                    String message = String.format("Unfortunately, item #%d does not exist.", item);
                    System.out.println(message);
                }

            // note how an exception is raised when we get an invalid input.
            // you must consider what happens when the input is invalid.
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Bad input. Try again.");
                keyboard.next();
            }
        } while (!itemFound);


        Double paid = null;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter the amount paid: ");
            try {
                paid = keyboard.nextDouble();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Bad input. Try again.");
                keyboard.next();
            }
        } while (paid == null);

        double itemValue = itemPrices[item-1];

        double change = paid - itemValue;

        double moneyNeeded = 0 - change;

        if ( moneyNeeded > 0 ) {
            // We can inform the user what the problem was. And again the String.format magic.
            String message = String.format("Please insert another $%.2f.%n", moneyNeeded);
            System.out.println(message);

            // But this time, we will gracefully exit.
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String message = String.format("Thank you for buying item #%d, your change is $%.2f. Please come again!", item, change);

        System.out.println(message);

    }

}
```

Would be much prettier if done using the Scala programming language.
Those loops could be replaced with tail recursion, absolutely no mutability (mutability is not pretty, but immutability is harder to do in Java).

**Edit:** Exercise for the reader: fix the `moneyNeeded` `if`-statement to have the correct "business"-logic. At the moment it quits having eaten all your money.

Answer (score 7):

Using floating-point data types to represent money is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/1157100), due to the inability to represent some rational numbers in binary.  Either use `java.math.BigDecimal` or work in cents instead of dollars.

Parsing a string representation of dollars and cents directly into an integer number of cents, is slightly tricky.  One approach is to use [`BigDecimal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2408469/1157100) to help with the parsing and conversion.